# compiling 64 bit linux kernel with gcc

Tags: linux, kernel, 64-bit, gcc

While trying to compile a 64 bit Linux kernel using GCC, I see the following error:

> kernel/bounds.c:1: error: code model ‘kernel’ not supported in the 32
> bit mode
>  kernel/bounds.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not
> compiled in

This is what `gcc -v` reports:

> Using built-in specs.
>  Target: i586-redhat-linux
>  Configured
> with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --
> infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/
> bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --
> enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --
> disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c+
> +,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable- plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --
> enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/
> usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl
> -- with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i586 --build=i586-redhat- linux
>  Thread model: posix
>  gcc version 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2) (GCC)

Am I missing something on my kernel make command line? Or is it the GCC present on the system does not support 64-bit compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your gcc -v output it looks as if you are running on a 32-bit machine, is that correct ?

```
Target: i586-redhat-linux
```

Try specifying --with-arch=x86_64 insterad of i586.

Comment: Its a Pentium 4. I would think that it supports 64 bit, though I am not sure. 
I already tried with 'make ARCH=x86_64' . Does not seem to help.

Comment: You are right. It was a 32 bit machine. I built a x86_64 cross compiler but that did not help either in building the kernel.

Comment: Where does the --with-arch get specified?